# Why is my PASSWORD_REQUIRED_TEMPLATE not found, but my direct override of login.html is found?

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to style a custom login page for private pages in Wagtail, as per the [docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html).

If I follow the recommended method (for my app `website`) and place my template in `'website/password_required.html'` (or `website/templates/password_required.html`), Wagtail does not pick up the new template. Instead it loads `wagtailcore/login.html`. I have tried several different locations for the customized template (including `website/templates/website/`. No location seems to catch it.

However, if I forego `PASSWORD_REQUIRED_TEMPLATE` and just directly override `login.html` with `website/templates/wagtailcore/login.html`, then it works. But I'd rather do this the right way than the way that just works.

I'm pretty sure that this is one of those situations where I've missed something small but crucial. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: What kind of permission restriction did you set up - "accessible to logged in users", or "accessible with the following (shared) password"? password_required.html is only used for the latter.

Comment: Ah yes, something simple. Of course. "Accessible to logged in users" is what I'm going for. So, for the styling of the correct login page (for logged in users), overriding login.html is the proper way?

Comment: OK, It looks like I've confused "the basic login page" mentioned in the private pages section of the docs with the main (/admin) login page (which is also a "basic login page"), and it sounds like WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE is the correct way. (testing...) Yup, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse the login page for private pages with Wagtail's main login page. The [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html#login-page) is clear if you start out with this distinction in mind.

For private pages, a template specified by `WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE` in the settings file is the correct method (and will provide a separate login page from the default).